# Oracle regular expression substring to add particular number in given string

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle regular expression `substring` to add particular number in given string

```
8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00
```

I am having above string and i need to add `8030`+`8017`+`8089` from the above string.

How do I solve it in oracle SQL or pl/SQL .

Comment: Are the fields always in the same format of '8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00'

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of mathematics, `SUBSTR`, `INSTR` & `REVERSE` to achieve this.

Literal String:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00',1,4) AS a,
SUBSTR(substr('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00', - instr(reverse('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00'), '/N/',1,2) - 6),1,4) AS b,
SUBSTR(substr('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00', - instr(reverse('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00'), '/N/',1,3) - 6),1,4) AS c,
(SUBSTR('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00',1,4) +
SUBSTR(substr('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00', - instr(reverse('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00'), '/N/',1,2) - 6),1,4) +
SUBSTR(substr('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00', - instr(reverse('8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00'), '/N/',1,3) - 6),1,4)) AS total
FROM dual
```

Using a field name:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(YOURFIELD,1,4) AS a,
SUBSTR(substr(YOURFIELD, - instr(reverse(YOURFIELD), '/N/',1,2) - 6),1,4) AS b,
SUBSTR(substr(YOURFIELD, - instr(reverse(YOURFIELD), '/N/',1,3) - 6),1,4) AS c,
(SUBSTR(YOURFIELD,1,4) +
SUBSTR(substr(YOURFIELD, - instr(reverse(YOURFIELD), '/N/',1,2) - 6),1,4) +
SUBSTR(substr(YOURFIELD, - instr(reverse(YOURFIELD), '/N/',1,3) - 6),1,4)) AS total
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Just the total:

```
SELECT (SUBSTR(YOURFIELD,1,4) +
SUBSTR(substr(YOURFIELD, - instr(reverse(YOURFIELD), '/N/',1,2) - 6),1,4) +
SUBSTR(substr(YOURFIELD, - instr(reverse(YOURFIELD), '/N/',1,3) - 6),1,4)) AS total
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your starting string contains a comma separated list of values, where each value is composed by 3 informations separated by `'/'`.

If so, a way coudl be by first identifying all the items and then "parse" them to extract the needed information and sum the result.

Say you have a table like this:

```
create table test(id, str) as (
    select 1, '8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00' from dual union all
    select 2, '8029/N/25.00,8000/N/25.00,1000/N/50.00' from dual
)
```

You can extract the items for each row with a commonly used split string technique:

```
SELECT id, regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) as item
  FROM test t
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

gives:

```
        ID ITEM
---------- ----------------
         1 8030/N/25.00
         1 8017/N/25.00
         1 8089/N/50.00
         2 8029/N/25.00
         2 8000/N/25.00
         2 1000/N/50.00
```

Now you have to extract the needed information ( I assume it always is exactly in the first 4 characters) and sum:

```
SELECT id, sum(to_char(substr(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level), 1, 4))) as the_sum
  FROM test t
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null   
group by id 

        ID    THE_SUM
---------- ----------
         1      24136
         2      17029
```

If the information to sum is not exactly in the first 4 characters, you simply have to edit the `SUBSTR` with some `REGEXP_SUBSTR` or whatever you need, depending on the structure of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) As
  SELECT '8030/N/25.00,8017/N/25.00,8089/N/50.00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(^|,)(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) )
       + TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(^|,)(\d+)', 1, 2, NULL, 2 ) )
       + TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(^|,)(\d+)', 1, 3, NULL, 2 ) )
         AS total
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
TOTAL
-----
24136
```